# Is the Bianchi-identity conformally invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

I am trying to show that for a conformal transformation $\tilde{g}_{ab} = \Omega^2 g_{ab}$ the divergence of the non-physical Einstein-tensor $\tilde{G}_{ab}$ (i.e. the Einstein tensor corresponding to the non-physical metric $\tilde{g}_{ab}$) vanishes with respect to the non-physical covariant derivative operator $\tilde{\nabla}^a$ (it is defined by being compatible with $\tilde{g}_{ab}$, i.e. $\tilde{\nabla}_a \tilde{g}_{cb} = 0$). In other words, I'm trying to show that $\tilde{\nabla}^a \tilde{G}_{ab}=0$.

I tried it with the following approach:

- started from the transformation rule $\tilde{g}_{ab} = \Omega^2 g_{ab}$
- I calculated how all the sufficient quantities ($\tilde{R}_{ab}$, $\tilde{R}$, $\tilde{\nabla}_a$) transform
- I calculated how the Einstein-tensor transforms
- Then in the equation $\nabla^a G_{ab}$ I substituted $\nabla^a$ and $G_{ab}$ with their non-physical counterparts, according to these transformation rules

However this method is utterly complex, and I didn't really see how all the extra terms coming from the transformation rules cancel each other out to arrive to $\tilde{\nabla}^a \tilde{G}_{ab} = 0$.

Here comes the main question of this post:
It is known that $\nabla^a G_{ab}=0$ is a direct consequence of (or alternatively another form for) the twice contracted Bianchi-identity. My question is, that is there a simple way to show that the Bianchi-identity is conformally invariant? In other words is is true that $\nabla_{[a}R_{bc]d}{}^e=\tilde{\nabla}_{[a}\tilde{R}_{bc]d}{}^e$?

Comment: I don't understand your question, your conformal transformation is a redefinition, and the Bianchi identity is, well, an identity in the mathematical sense.  So since the contracted Bianchi identity is automatically satisfied for a metric $g$, it is satisfied for $\tilde{g}=\Omega^2 g$.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux this is exactly what I am trying to show, by an exact calculation. In other words what is the mathematical reason behind the fact that if $g$ satisfies the Bianchi identity, then $\Omega^2 g$ automatically does as well.

Comment: Every metric can be considered as a conformal transformation of another metric. Again, the Bianchi identity is an identity in the mathematical sense, it is not an equality so whether you write your metric $\tilde{g}$ as $\Omega^2 g$ or directly $\tilde{g}$ doesn't change anything to the result.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Ahh okay, now I get it, thank you very much for your replies!